# I am getting "defined in an assembly that is not referenced" errors when building my c# project, how to solve it?

Tags: c#, .net

I have already have references to System and System.Data.

> 1.The type 'System.ComponentModel.IListSource' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> 2.The type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> 3.The type 'System.Data.IDataRecord' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> 4.The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I have already have references to System and System.Data.

Comment: You have not referenced the above DLL's to your project that's why

Comment: To add the DLL's Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Answer (score 17):

Restarting Visual Studio resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the best :D ... love this community. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add references to assemblies where there type are defines. 
To add reference to an assembly; right click on the Reference nodes under your project and select the assemblies node on the left tree and

1. add reference to `System.dll`, which will show up as System on the right side
2. add reference to `System.Data.dll`, which will show up as `System.Data` on the right side

Comment: the problem is that I have already have references to System and System.Data.

Comment: Is the assembly present at the location from where it is being referenced? Try removing and adding the reference.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayds71se.aspx

Comment: nothing happens... and also I cant change the Target Framework version

Comment: How to do this with Unity project?
there is no option to add reference in Unity

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was getting error as

> You must add a reference to assembly netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0

It was resolved by following steps

1. In Visual studio - Solution explorer right click on the project and choose unload so that you are able to edit the .proj file.
2. Locate the last tag of   tags in side the t tag.
3. After  add an new tag as below:

```html
   <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

4. Save the file.
5. Again right click on project and choose Reload project.

Answer (score 0):

This kind error can happen in the following case

1. You reference come DLL. In your project you have

```xml
<Reference Include="Some.Assembly, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=32bf3556ab364c35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\bin\Some.Assembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

2. You need to upgrade this dll.

- You drop your new DLL into the bin (see `HintPath`). And if this DLL has a different public key, or does not have a public key, when you build your project, you will get this exact error

Solution in this case - reset reference. Delete existing reference and add it again.

In my case it happened when one DLL I've used wasn't an open source, then became one. I've built it myself and replaced an old dll.